# Legendre symbol for a prime of the form $m^2-dn^2$

Tags: number-theory, legendre-symbol

Let $p$ be a prime of the form $p=a^2-db^2$ with $d$ square-free and $a,b \in \Bbb Z$

Prove that $(\frac{d}{p})=1$.

We have $(\frac{d}{p})(\frac{b^2}{p})=(\frac{a^2}{p})$

Hence $(\frac{d}{p})\ge 0$

I don't see a contradiction with the case $(\frac{d}{p})= 0$.I think it is related to the condition $d$ is square-free but I don't see it.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be something missing from the set of problem conditions because a fairly simple counter-example of $p = 5, a = 5, d = 5, b = 2$ gives $5 = 5^2 - 5(2^2)$ and meets the other stated conditions, but you then have $\left(\frac{d}{p}\right)=0$.

However, if you also have $\gcd(d,p) = 1$, then if $p \mid b$ you have $p \mid a$, and vice-versa, so $p^2 \mid a^2 - db^2$, which is not possible, so $\gcd(a,p) = \gcd(b,p) = 1$, which means $\left(\frac{a^2}{p}\right) = \left(\frac{b^2}{p}\right) = 1$. Thus, as you stated, $\left(\frac{d}{p}\right)\left(\frac{b^2}{p}\right) = \left(\frac{a^2}{p}\right)$ gives the result of $\left(\frac{d}{p}\right)=1$ as requested. However, I don't see how the requirement of $d$ being square-free makes any difference in this situation.

Comment: omienlan,I think it's implicitly understood that  $(\frac{a}{p})$ is defined only when $(a,p)=1$

Comment: @HVxvejjw The [Defintion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_symbol#Definition) section of Wikipedia's "Legendre Symbol" article says $\left(\frac{a}{p}\right) = 0$ if $a \equiv 0 \pmod p$. Thus, it's defined and given a value of $0$.

Comment: omielan, then I think $d$ must be a composite squarefree integer, or else the question would be wrong.

Comment: @HVxvejjw As I stated in my answer, there's something wrong with the question with my simple counter-example. I don't think requiring $d$ to be a composite square-free integer would be sufficient, but I haven't checked into this. Also, to ping me, please use "@" followed by the first letter or two of my name so you can press "tab" to choose my name. As it is, you've misspelled my surname twice now.

Comment: Sorry about that.

Comment: @HVxvejjw No worries. As I just recalled now, I don't think the "@" option works here for me since I will be pinged by any comments to my answer, so the system won't let you use it directly by giving you the choice of my name. If so, then I'm sorry for suggesting you use that "@" option to ping me.